# Can I get a card from the hatching feathers?

Tags: botanicula

Can I do anything further with these hatching feathers? Whenever I click the eggs, a new feather creature hatches and then another one comes along and lays another egg. I've tried clicking on all the eggs in an area at once while trying to click on as many of the other creatures at the same time, but that seems to get me nowhere.

**Note** that I've already

> acquired the key here by hatching the glowing white flying creatures. I've also received the white flying creature card.

However, I'm wondering if there's a card to be had with these leftover hatching ones, or is this as much as I can do here?

[image: feathers1]
[image: feathers2]

This is the location of these areas:
[image: map]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no feather creature card**, but there is one for the white creatures, as you mentioned.<sup>[1](http://www.gamezebo.com/games/botanicula/walkthrough)</sup>

[image: white creature card from Gamezebo walkthrough]<sup>[1](http://www.gamezebo.com/games/botanicula/walkthrough)</sup>